# How to redirect python logger info to a log file in python

Tags: python, logging

I want to write all of python logger messages to a log file.
I have this code, but the code displays messages on the console and just creates the log file, but writes nothing to it.

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='tmp.log')
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handlers = [file_handler, stdout_handler]

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
    handlers=handlers
)
logger = logging.getLogger("somename")
```

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: You mean you want to log all `sys.stdout` to a file rather than to console?

Comment: I tried your code example, it logs messages both to `sys.stdout` and to `tmp.log`

Comment: @Lakshita Ranasingha yes i want to print just to the log

Comment: @Sanya..in my case it just creates the file tmp.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do, this instead:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
    filename='tmp.log'
)
logging.debug("somename")
```

If `filename` parameter is provided in `basicConfig` it means the file is opened in this mode. The default is `a`, which means **append**.